# ScheduledExecutorService worker threads retain interrupted status after FutureTask.cancel(true)

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, interrupt, executorservice

I have a task which I schedule to run periodically via [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, rate, ...)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29).  A user can cancel this task manually, which invokes [ScheduledFuture.cancel(true)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel%28boolean%29).  For some reason, perhaps depending on when they cancel this task, the worker thread (which the executor used to run my task) appears to remain in an interrupted status after my task's run() method exits.

I would have though that worker threads (taken from a pool and reused) would have their interrupted status cleared before starting a new task using the existing hooks (via [ThreadPoolExecutor.beforeExecute()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#beforeExecute%28java.lang.Thread,%20java.lang.Runnable%29) or [ThreadPoolExecutor.afterExecute()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#afterExecute%28java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.Throwable%29)).  But it does not do this in the default implementation.

I have two questions:

- How is it that the worker thread is left in a state where the interrupt status is set?
- Why does the default implementation not clear the interrupt status before starting a new task?

Comment: I couldn't see this behavior despite using a variety of timings. Can you describe how to reproduce this reliably?

Comment: I wish I understood it better myself, the task itself uses ArrayBlockingQueue.take() which uses ReentrantLock.lockInterruptibly().  I believe this has something to do with it, I am still trying to get a handle on how it happens (second part of the question)

Comment: Which JDK (version, vendor, OS, etc.) are you using?

Comment: I think I found it: the task starts a separate prefetch thread which puts work units into a queue, a shutdown race condition left a terminator work unit into the queue forcing an early shutdown which re-triggers the race condition (and interrupting the thread).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> * How is it that the worker thread is left in a state where the interrupt status is set?
> * Why does the default implementation not clear the interrupt status before starting a new task?
> ```

The answers are:

- It is not left in an interrupted state.
- The implementation does but you are not looking in the right spot

From the Oracle library code:

```
        /*
         * Ensure that unless pool is stopping, this thread
         * does not have its interrupt set. This requires a
         * double-check of state in case the interrupt was
         * cleared concurrently with a shutdownNow -- if so,
         * the interrupt is re-enabled.
         */
        if (runState < STOP &&
            Thread.interrupted() &&
            runState >= STOP)
            thread.interrupt();
```

As you can see, the interrupt state is cleared from the worker thread so long as the executor is not shutting down.

Comment: True that!  I saw that piece of code the first time and misread it as only applying when pool was shutting down.  I still have no idea how I am getting the interrupted exception; perhaps I'm canceling and scheduling the task at the same time without realizing it.

Comment: If the user cancels while the task is executing, how do you handle the InterruptedException which will be thrown at the next blocked call?

Comment: I just catch it, log it and return (its a restartable batch process)

Answer (score -1):

How is the user interrupting the thread?  If they're using a UI component, your issue may be due to synchronization problems with the event dispatch thread.

Comment: It is not a swing application.  As it says in the question: the task (a FutureTask) is canceled by some arbitrary thread via `ScheduledFuture.cancel(true)`.